# Why does my while do loop breaks after selecting and using any case in my switch?

Tags: c++

I want program to keep printing until I select 'a' or 'A' But after I select anything and insert certain things .. it breaks, it should keep repeating until I select 'a' or 'A'. that while should be good or am I mistaken?

this is my loop.

```
char select;
do {
  cout << " MENUE \n";
  cout << "A  \n";
  cout << "B  \n";
  cout << "C  \n";
  cout << "D  \n";
  cout << "E  \n";
  cout << "F  \n";
  cout << "G  \n";
  cout << "H  \n";
  cout << "your choice: ";
  cin >> select;

  switch (select) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A': {
      cout << "bye bye";
      break;
    }

    case 'b':
    case 'B': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

    case 'c':
    case 'C': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

    case 'd':
    case 'D': {
      // code.;
      break;
    }

    case 'e':
    case 'E': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

    case 'f':
    case 'F': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

    case 'g':
    case 'G': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

    case 'h':
    case 'H': {
      // code.
      break;
    }

  }  // closing bracket of switch.
}  // closing bracket of do-while loop.
while (select != 'a' || select != 'A');
return 0;
}
```

I know this is mostly code but I don't know what else to write.

Comment: You mean it stops before you enter `'a'` or `'A'`? Then something else must be wrong, because the condition `select != 'a' || select != 'A'` will always be true.

Comment: OT: if utf-8 characters are not (!) present or in use, .tolower() could clear up your loop and your needed cases.

Comment: When you say that the loop "breaks", do you mean that the code breaks out of the loop and stops, or do you mean that the loop seems broken because it never stops?

Answer (score 4):

The condition for the while loop is always true:

```
while (select != 'a' || select != 'A')
```

Since `select` can only either be `'a'` or `'A'` at least one of both conditions always holds. So your loop will be repeating forever.

Do you mean

```
while (select != 'a' && select != 'A')
```

or equivalently (DeMorgan's law)

```
while (!(select == 'a' || select == 'A'))
```

Comment: While this is true, it does not answer the actual question. _"Why does my while do loop breaks after ..."_ i.e. OPs loop breaks for some, as of yet unknown, reason.

Comment: " I select anything and insert certain things ..", to be honest I even not sure what " it breaks" means in that context... break `switch`, break `do-while`, segmentation fault, normal exit...

Comment: First lecture on any IT subject should be 'How to ask questions on StackOverflow'